# What is the "best practice" way of passing specific "types" of Strings to functions?

Tags: java

For example, I have a class that has two strings, one of which must be set, the other of which could be null:

```
public class SomeClass{
    private String s1;
    private String s2;

    ...
}
```

I could define a constructor as follows:

```
public SomeClass(String s1, String s2){
    if(s1 == null && s2 == null) throw new SomeKindOfException("can't both be null");

    this.s1 = s1;
    this.s2 = s2;
}
```

I would rather do something along the lines of:

```
public SomeClass(String s1){
    this.s1 = s1;
}

public SomeClass(String s2){
    this.s2 = s2;
}
```

Which obviously can't work because it defines two methods that take the same number and type of parameters.

So, I would like to do something like:

```
public SomeClass(SomeTypeOfString s1){
    this.s1 = s1;
}

public SomeClass(AnotherTypeOfString s2){
    this.s2 = s2;
}
```

This has the added advantage that the "types" of String could validate their contents (e.g. SomeTypeOfString must be 6 chars long and AnotherTypeOfString must be between 4 and 8 chars long and only contain alpha-numeric chars.

Also, it makes it clearer, when calling a function, what data should be passed in.

So firstly, **does this *concept* sound sensible?**

In terms of implementation, you cannot extend String. You could wrap it though. The "types" of String are essentially types of String, so it would make sense to have them extend an abstract wrapper class. This could be implemented as follows:

```
public abstract class StringWrapper{
    private final String string;

    public StringWrapper(String string){
        this.string = string;
    }

    public String getString(){
        return string;
    }
}

public class SomeTypeOfString extends StringWrapper{
    public SomeTypeOfString(String string){
        super(string);
    }
}
```

The code for the SomeTypeOfString class looks rather silly, as all it does is define a constructor that calls the super-class's constructor... But assuming you also add some validation in there, it looks sensible to me. **Does this *implementation* sound sensible?**

Can anyone think of a **better concept** to solve the basic problem, or a **better implementation** for the concept I outlined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your concept and implementation do look sensible and can even improve readability if used consistently.

For example if one "type" of string represents a product id, then you can produce this class:

```
public abstract class ProductID{
    private final String id;

    public StringWrapper(String id){
        Preconditions.checkNotNull(id, "Can't construct a ProductID from null");
        Preconditions.checkArgument(isValidId(id), "%s is not a valid Product ID", id);
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getID(){
        return id;
    }

    public static boolean isValidID(id) {
      // check format
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return (o instanceof ProductID && ((ProductID) o).id.equals(this.id));
    }

    public boolean hashCode() {
        return id.hashCode();
    }

    public String toString() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

Note that `equals()`/`hashCode()` is necessary to be able to use `ProductID` as a key in a `Map` or to ensure uniqueness in a `Set` and similar things (apart from being generally useful). `toString()` can *either* be useful as a debug tool (in which case I'd add the class name, maybe using the neat [`MoreObjects.toStringHelper()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/base/MoreObjects.html#toStringHelper(java.lang.String)) approach or manually) *or* for rendering the product id in a way that is used on the UI (in which case the given implementation might be fine).

This has several advantages:

- you know that *every* `ProductID` object holds a *valid* product id (at least syntactically)
- methods that takes a `ProductID` make it *very* explicit what that value holds. If they accept a `String` instead it's not so clear.
- You can *easily* distinguish between two methods that take some IDs just from their argument type.

Unfortunately I can't say that I have experience with such a system in any large-scale systems (I used it plenty in smaller systems). But some disadvantages that I've seen and/or can imagine are this:

- external APIs: If some code calls you, it can usually handle `String`, but not `ProductID`, so you'll need to convert
- there will be places where you *still* need to use bare `String` values: when the user enters a value, you *might* need to be able to store it, even if it's *not* a valid product id.
- mindshare: developers need to buy into this concept, really grasp it and embrace it. Otherwise you end up with an ugly mix of `String`/`ProductID` with tons of conversion everywhere.

From these three, I think the last one is the most severe.

If, however, this seems like overkill to you, then using factory methods instead of constructors could be a solution:

```
public class SomeClass{
    private String s1;
    private String s2;

    private SomeClass(String s1, String s2) {
      Preconditions.checkArguments(s1 != null || s2 != null, "One of s1 or s2 must be non-null!");
      this.s1 = s1;
      this.s2 = s2;
    }

    public static SomeClass fromSomeString(String s1) {
      return new SomeClass(s1, null);
    }

    public static SomeClass fromAnotherString(String s2) {
      return new SomeClass(null, s2);
    }

    public static SomeClass fromStrings(String s1, String s2) {
      return new SomeClass(s1, s2);
    }
}
```

Note that I use the Guava [`Preconditions`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.html) class to shorten the argument checking code.

Comment: Thanks Joachim, that's exactly what I meant. I'm trying to find problems with this approach (to convince myself that it is the correct thing to do). Can you see any disadvantages aside from needing to write some extra classes?

Comment: Thanks for the expansion. Which approach would you favour? The first approach seems a little cleaner to me. @Kevin proposed a builder pattern. What do you think of that approach compared to the factory pattern or the string wrapper approach? Also, Guava's Preconditions looks handy. Thanks for the link.

Comment: @Spycho: in isolation, the builder or factory is definitely the simpler solution (and not significantly less clear either). *But* if you have a chance to *consistently* use meaningful classes intead of `String` in your *entire* project, then I'd definitely do that. If all you can (or want to) change is that one class, then I would go with a builder or factory. (And builder or factory methods is mostly a question of taste in this case, so I won't give a suggestion either way).

Comment: Thanks Joachim. I'm was thinking of rolling out typed Strings application wide, so that may be a better option than having a factory / builder for every class that could store the type of string.

Answer (score 5):

You could use a builder. I.e.

```
public SomeClassBuilder {
    String s1;
    String s2;
    public SomeClassBuilder someString1(String s) {
        this.s1 = s;
        return this;
    }
    public SomeClassBuilder someString2(String s) {
        this.s2 = s;
        return this;
    }
    public SomeClass build() {
        SomeClass sc = new SomeClass();

        // if one of s1 or s2 must be null, or you have some other sort of validation, you could do that here, e.g.
        if (s1 != null && s2 != null) throw new RuntimeException("not what I expected");
        else if (s1 == null && s2 == null) throw new RuntimeException("at least set one value");
        sc.setS1(s1);
        sc.setS2(s2);
        return sc;
    }

}
```

Usage would be:

```
   SomeClass sc = new SomeClassBuilder().someString1("xxx").someString2("yyy").build();
```

Or:

```
  SomeClass sc = new SomeClassBuilder().someString2("abc").build();
```

For only two constructor parameters the benefit is relatively minor but as the inputs increase the readability benefits grow.

Comment: need to check that at least one of s1 or s2 is not null before building.

Comment: What if you tried to do `SomeClass sc = new SomeClassBuilder().build();`? Would you have explicit checks in the build method to ensure that required variables had been set?

Comment: I wanted to recomand same thing. Its advantage over classical facotry is, that you dont have to have lot of similar function if number of optional parameters increase and it can add all the safety that "typed" strings offer (as long as only builder can acces actual construcor).

Comment: @user: that advantage is great *if* you have a big number of possibilities. With just 2 possible values to set the difference becomes much smaller.

Comment: Thanks. @Kevin, What do you think of the builder pattern compared to the factory pattern approach and typed string approach that Joachim proposed?

Answer (score 3):

The *domain specific* approach seems to complex to me, why not simply defining different constructors:

```
public class SomeClass {
    private final String mandatoryString;
    private String optionalString;
    ...

    public SomeClass(final String mandatoryString) {
        this(mandatoryString, null);
    }

    public SomeClass(final String mandatoryString, final String optionalString) {
        this.mandatoryString = mandatoryString;
        this.optionalString = optionalString;
    }

}
```

**EDIT: Value Object example**

```
public class SomeClass {

    public SomeClass(ValueObject vo) {
        if (vo == null) {
            // exception...
        } else if (vo.getS1() == null && vo.getS2() == null) {
            // exception...
        }
        // proceed...
    }
}

public class ValueObject {
    private String s1;
    private String s2;

    public ValueObject(String s1, String s2) {
        this.s1 = s1;
        this.s2 = s2;
    }

    // getters here...
}
```

Using a *Value Object* or *Domain Specific Object* decouples data collection from corresponding logic. A well defined (dumb) business object (ValueObject) maintains the state of your application, *SomeClass* is responsible for validating and processing the given business object.

**EDIT 2:** The *Builder* pattern as propsed in other answers may also cover your requirements. Although it is a valid approach it may be too complex in the context of your use case. It all depends on complexity...

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough. There is no single mandatory string. _One_ of them is mandatory but it doesn't matter which. Either s1 must be passed in or s2 must be passed in.

Comment: @Spycho: Then you should have some kind of value object to be passed to the constructor. You may also want to have a look at enums...

Comment: sorry, @home, I don't quite follow... What do you mean by having some kind of value object passed to the constructor? How would you solve this problem with enums? Would you mind elaborating a little?

Comment: @Spycho: Sorry for not being specific enough. Given your comments on previous answers, the `enum` approach does not seem to be valid. I've updated the answer with a value object example.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating. That's an interesting approach that I hadn't considered. I up-voted because I think it's worth considering this approach, but I think I would rather have the business object checking itself for validity in it's constructor, rather than leaving it to the thing that uses the business object. In my original example, SomeClass _is_ the business object.

Comment: @Spycho: I agree, as I tried to explain in my answer it depends on how you use those object sand the complexity of the overall solution. My experience is it's easy to maintain really, really dumb value objects, although it is not really the object oriented way...

Answer (score 1):

It seems to much of a trouble to me.. I'd write one constructor, with one string parameter - the string that must not be null. In the constructor I'd check for null, and if so - throw an exception.
About the second string - you have two options, or provide another constructor with 2 strings that calls the first constructor, or provide a setter method to a set a value for that second string.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough. One of the strings must not be null. It doesn't matter which. I.e. either s1 must not be null or s2 must not be null. But regardless of that circumstance, what about the validation logic? And increased parameter specificity? You think it's not worth having that?

Answer (score 1):

How about if you use a couple of static "builder" methods:

```
public SomeClass(String s1, String s2) {
    if(s1 == null && s2 == null)
        throw new SomeKindOfException("can't both be null");
    this.s1 = s1;
    this.s2 = s2;
}

public static SomeClass newSomeClassFromS1(String s1){
    return new SomeClass(s1, null);
}

public static SomeClass newSomeClassFromS2(String s2){
    return new SomeClass(null, s2);
}
```